# Should I include .sass-cache with the repo when versioning a web project?

Tags: git, caching, sass, gitignore, repository

When creating a new project or upgrading an older one, should I conclude the .sass-cache directory in the repo? Since that is always changing and depends on the preprocessor to run wouldn't it be easier to ignore? What are the benefits of including the cache dirs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you shouldn't include the directory. The general rule is to not include any files generated by some automated process from version control. Including generated files can make merging difficult, adds spurious diffs into commits, and can make your repository awkward to browse, to give a few reasons.

*(There are some notable exceptions, like including `db/schema.rb` or `Gemfile.lock` for Rails projects.)*

Comment: Thank you. That was quite helpful.